# Javascript: Continous for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am in need of assistance. I have created some code that puts the vowels in an interval. It is working fine, however, once it cycles through the 6 letters (aeiouy) it stops. How will I be able to make this loop continuously and loop through letters indefinitely?

Thanks in advance!

```js
// Vowel string
var vowels = 'aeiouy'.split('');

// start button
levelButton2.addEventListener("click", function () {
    for (y = 0; y < vowels.length; y++) {
       setTimeout(() => getRandom(vowels), y*1000);
    }
});


// Function that gives me random letters

function getRandom (letters) {
    var randomSet = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    console.log('set random' , randomSet)
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = randomSet;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's a  good idea to make your snippet runnable by including all relevant markup. See [mcve] and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you get rid of the For loop and just add the settimeout in your getRandom function it will continue non stop.

```js
// Vowel string
var vowels = 'aeiouy'.split('');
var _timer;
var levelButton2 = document.querySelector(".levelButton2");
var levelButton3 = document.querySelector(".levelButton3");
// start button
levelButton2.addEventListener("click", function () {
   getRandom(vowels);
});

// stop button
levelButton3.addEventListener("click", function () {
   clearTimeout(_timer);
});


// Function that gives me random letters

function getRandom (letters) {
    var randomSet = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    console.log('set random' , randomSet)
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = randomSet;
    _timer = setTimeout(() => getRandom(vowels), 1000);
};
```

```html
<button type="button" class="levelButton2">START</button>
<button type="button" class="levelButton3">STOP</button>
<div id="demo3"></div>
```

Comment: Should clear the existing timer or skip scheduling if a timer exists on subsequent clicks of start